# Output all licenses of installed node.js libraries

Tags: node.js, npm

Is there an option in npm (or other tool) to print all used licenses?
I have a project and I want to make sure I don't use a library which is under a license I can't use.

EDIT: Found out that many developers don't include the license in the package.json, so I had to find out manually using "npm docs package-name"

Comment: Little late to the party but npm grunt-license does exactly what you want - This assuming grunt is or will be used ;)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
cd {project}/node_modules
ls | sed 's/$/\/package.json/' | xargs grep '"license[s]*"' -A 3
```

Could use some improvement, but it works (at least on osx, should work on linux, no idea about windows). You should see something like:

```
grunt/package.json:  "licenses": [
grunt/package.json-    {
grunt/package.json-      "type": "MIT",
grunt/package.json-      "url": "http://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/LICENSE-MIT"
--
grunt-contrib-concat/package.json:  "licenses": [
grunt-contrib-concat/package.json-    {
grunt-contrib-concat/package.json-      "type": "MIT",
grunt-contrib-concat/package.json-      "url": "https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat/blob/master/LICENSE-MIT"
--
```

**Update:**

If you wish to see the name of all modules, even those nested inside other modules, the following works (cred to @robertklep, slightly modified to still work when inside the node_modules directory):

```
find * -name package.json | xargs grep '"license[s]*"' -A 3
```

Comment: Wouldn't show any nested modules though. How about `find node_modules -name package.json | xargs grep ...`?

Comment: @robertklep true, I'll add your variant to the answer. My thought was that if a license is viral (eg GPL), the modules depending on it must have a compatible license. Then there should be no need to check nested modules?

Comment: I don't know what licences can't be used by @whadar, although I think your assumption of GPL is correct. But an MIT-licensed module can list a GPL-licensed module as a dependency, and if a specific version that's required it will be installed as a nested module I think.

Comment: ***This is a dangerous answer***. This should not of been marked as the answer nor should it ever be used. If you have modules where the licenses are located in other parts of the module this will 1) not pick it up 2) not alert you that it cannot find a license for that module. Do not use this.

Answer (score 71):

I had exactly the same requirement, and wrote a node module to do this. Shameless self promotion I know, but it is open source and hope it can help resolve your issue.  Let me know if you have any issues or suggestions.

The difference over the other answers is that it does not just use the package.json license declaration, but looks for potential license information in license and readme files in the project.

https://npmjs.org/package/nlf

You can install using `npm install -g nlf`

Comment: The best part about `nlf` is passing the CLI argument `-c` to get CSV output -- so you run `nlf -c -r 0 > licenses.csv` and you'll get all of the root-level dependencies with the license types and links to their repos. The perfect output to give to your legal team :-)

Comment: This is a great project, thanks for sharing @iandotkelly. For my needs, I used the command `nlf -c -r 20 > licenses-alllevels.csv` to cover all the recursive levels.

Answer (score 26):

Yarn has a command for this as well. [`yarn licenses list`](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/licenses/) renders short output, `yarn licenses generate-disclaimer` renders all the **actual license text** to stdout (suitable for disclaimers, as the option would imply).

- If you want to omit `devDependencies`:

  ```
  NODE_ENV=production yarn licenses list
  ```
- For my purposes, the following command got me close enough:

  ```
  yarn licenses list | grep License | \
  grep -vE 'MIT|ISC|WTFPL|BSD|Apache|Unlicense|CC-BY|Public Domain'`
  ```

Comment: Good tool but the update is not easily parsable for further scripting

Comment: With yarn2 this doesn't work anymore, see issue on GitHub https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/1164. However, there is a plugin (https://github.com/mhassan1/yarn-plugin-licenses) that tries to solve it.

Answer (score 14):

Take a look at [license-report](https://github.com/ironSource/license-report) or [license-checker](https://github.com/davglass/license-checker)

Answer (score 11):

Having just done this for a large project, I can say it turns out this process is more of a headache to automate fully than you might think. It's easy to get many of them with some of the tricks listed here, but NPM package licenses are not published consistently, and can appear

- In the NPM package.json file, or
- In the README file (sometimes just the name, like "MIT license", and sometimes full license text in a section), or
- In a separate LICENSE or COPYING file.

In addition, you sometimes have to read a licenses to tell which well-known open source license it corresponds to.

The best tool I know to do this, that (unlike some of the other answers here) covers all these cases is the **licensecheck** package:
https://github.com/marcello3d/node-licensecheck

It looks at package.json as well as common license files, and does a signature match against known licenses, so it accurately recognizes more licenses automatically. It also "normalizes" licenses against the standard SPDX list of licenses (https://spdx.org/licenses/).

Finally, Licensecheck also lets you save any remaining packages you needed to manually verify in your own license.json file (since you can't count on an external maintainer to change their package).

Taken together, this is a pretty robust solution.

Comment: The latest version does not appear to output SPDX identifiers.

Answer (score 3):

I liked the question, and took the time to write a nodejs script for it:

```
var npm = require('npm');
npm.load(process.config,function(err){
    npm.list(function(err,deps){
        var names = Object.keys(deps.dependencies);
        for(var i in names){
            var depen = deps.dependencies[names[i]];
            console.log('Licenses for :',names[i]);
            depen.licenses.forEach(function(license,i){
                console.log('License #'+(i+1));
                console.log('- Title:',license.type);
                console.log('- Url:\t',license.url);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

this will output each license name and url for each module,

**NOTE:** must be executed in project folder and npm must be installed (`npm install npm -g` sounds overkill but this is the npm js lib)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this it you are on a Linux based system:

```
npm list -g --depth=0 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -i npm view {} | grep license
```

You will have something like this:

```
  license: 'MIT',
  license: 'MIT',
  license: 'MIT',
  license: 'BSD',
  license: 'MIT',
  license: 'MIT',
  license: 'BSD-2-Clause',
  license: 'MIT',
  .....................
  .....................
  .....................
  license: 'BSD-2-Clause',
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick and easy way to check:

`npx license-checker --summary`

Great source for more information:  https://medium.com/@fokusman/the-easiest-way-to-check-all-your-npm-dependency-licenses-753075ef1d9d

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get all licenses from a directory or it subdirectories you can use NPM License Crawler https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-license-crawler. It was the best solution for me

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Atom, there is [npm-license-checker](https://atom.io/packages/npm-license-checker) to get the licenses from `package.json`.